# How to keep current tab active on toggling the ul in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to keep active the tab, which I selected while toggling the CDNA. Please find the UI and code below:

[image: CDNA active tab]

So as per the Image, I have selected the "Segment View" so, while I am clicking on CDNA and open it again then "Segment View" should remain active.

Please help.

```html
<ul class="nav side-menu " id="tree3">
  <li style="background-color: #01AE9D;border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;" class="campaignCentral active">
    <a id="cdnaAnchor" class="sep">
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>CDNA</span>
      <span id="arrowImage" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></span>
    </a>
    <ul t-ng-resize class="nav child_menu" style="display: block;">
      <li ng-class="currentState == 'individual' ? 'active':''" class="parentLi">
        <a ui-sref="individual">
          <i class="fa fa-street-view" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <span data-ng-show="!resized">Customer View</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="currentState == 'segment' ? 'active':''" class="parentLi">
        <a ui-sref="segment">
          <i class="fa fa-pie-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <span data-ng-show="!resized">Segment View</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="currentState == 'merchant' ? 'active':''" class="parentLi">
        <a ui-sref="merchant">
          <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <span data-ng-show="!resized">Merchant View</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="currentState == 'product' ? 'active':''" class="parentLi">
        <a ui-sref="product">
          <i class="fa fa-sitemap" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <span data-ng-show="!resized">Product View</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="currentState == 'dashboard' ? 'active':''" class="parentLi">
        <a ui-sref="dashboard">
          <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <span data-ng-show="!resized">Exec Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Creating a JS Fiddle showing your problem will help you get an answer.

Comment: Creating a stackoverflow-snippet that demonstrates the issue will get even more help (than a js fiddle, which is generally recommended against these days)